# docker service create image command like `docker run`

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

Does anyone use docker service create with command like `docker run -it ubuntu bash` ?

e.g: `docker service create --name test redis bash`.

I want to run a temp container for debugging on production environment in swarm mode with the same network.

This is my result:

```
user@ubuntu ~/$ docker service ps test
ID                         NAME        IMAGE  NODE    DESIRED STATE  CURRENT STATE            ERROR
bmig9qd9tihw7q1kff2bn42ab  test.1      redis  ubuntu  Ready          Ready 3 seconds ago
9t4za9r4gb03az3af13akpklv   \_ test.1  redis  ubuntu  Shutdown       Complete 4 seconds ago
1php2be7ilp7psulwp31b3ib4   \_ test.1  redis  ubuntu  Shutdown       Complete 10 seconds ago
drwyjdggd13n1emb66oqchmuv   \_ test.1  redis  ubuntu  Shutdown       Complete 15 seconds ago
b1zb5ja058ni0b4c0etcnsltk   \_ test.1  redis  ubuntu  Shutdown       Complete 21 seconds ago
```

Answer (score 0):

When you create a service that startup Bash it will imediately stop because it is in detached mode.
You can have the same behavior if you run `docker run -d ubuntu bash`

Comment: Sorry, my description may be  unclear. I want to use `docker service create` startup an container, just like `docker run -it ubuntu bash` did.
Now docker service may be not support the "exit mode after run an command".

Comment: A service can only be started in detached mode, a solution is to start like this `docker service create ubuntu tail -f /dev/null` so there is a process preventing the container to stop. Then you just have to use `docker exec -it nameofservice.********* bash` and you will have an access to bash.

Comment: I run `docker service create ubuntu tail -f /dev/null` on my server, and the service is still detached mode. I thought it may be limited in docker swarm.  So, now, I have to build an debug image for debugging, and jump into with `docker exec -it  .... command`.